# Send multiple API requests when user asks for large dataset

Tags: c#, .net, api, odata

I've created a GET request with Odata but the API is slow when I try to retrieve all of the data. What I wanted to do was split the request to a few multiple requests. As each request is returned then I wanted to append it to what's already on the client end. I've put in a snippet of some of my code and I've omitted parts of it eg checking for null values/parsing etc. Is it possible to do it from one controller or would I need to do something else?

A detailed explanation would be appreciated!

```
[HttpGet]
[Microsoft.AspNetCore.OData.Query.EnableQuery(PageSize = pageSize)]
public IActionResult GetVendors(ODataQueryOptions<VendorsModel> options)
{
    int accountID = int.Parse(options.Filter.RawValue);
    int pageSize = 5000;
    IQueryable<model> model = Enumerable.Empty<model>().AsQueryable();
    var top = int.Parse(options.Top.RawValue);
    int remaining = top;
    if (top > pageSize)
    {
        do
        {
            model = Enumerable.Empty<model>().AsQueryable(); //reset model so I do not have any duplicates when I append the data.
            model = context.GetModel.Where(x => x.AccountID == accountID).Skip(top -  remaining).Take(pageSize);

            Ok(model); //This is where I would like to update the front-end from.

            remaining -= pageSize;
        } while (remaining > pageSize);

        model = context.GetModel.Where(x => x.AccountID == accountID).Skip(top - remaining).Take(remaining);

         return Ok(model); // return final part of the data.
    }
}
```

Comment: Is code hanging up during queue?  If so fix the hangup instead of doing multiple queries.

Comment: The DB has 100,000s of records so it'll take a while to retrieve all of them. I wanted to use pagination but if someone is requesting all the data I don't want them to manually have to request the next page 100s of times. I wanted to automate that by appending the data to the end of it.

Comment: Why is it taking so long to get data?  Using a SQL Server 0.5 million take a couple of seconds.  You can not break one HTTP request/response into parts.  You have to wait until the end.  Or send multiple request/responses.